# Are starters guaranteed perfect IVs?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

So I've been playing Pokemon Lets Go Eevee for a while now, and I unlocked the IV checker. I checked my starter Eevee's IVs and all of the stats say best on it. Am I guaranteed perfect IVs on my starter or am I just really lucky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The starters in the Let's Go series are guaranteed perfect IVs. According to [this guide](https://nintendosoup.com/pokemon-lets-go-pikachu-eevee-starters-have-flawless-ivs-but-cannot-be-shiny/), it's hardcoded as such in the game code, and the perfect IVs is also confirmed on [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/partner.shtml).

In addition to having perfect IVs, the starters also have higher base stats compared to others in their species:

- [Pikachu's](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pikachu_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Partner_Pikachu) base stats are 430 as opposed to 320
- [Eevee's](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eevee_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Partner_Eevee) base stats are 435 are opposed to 325